# Lost input focus when trying to update an array of objects in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update (onchange) the state in an array of objects, but I'm losing the input focus every time that I type something.

Any idea why this is happening?

Here is a Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-booth-636tx

```
 {stagesState.map(stage => {
        return (
          <div key={uuidv4()}>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={e => {
                const name = e.target.value;
                setStagesState(currentStage =>
                  currentStage.map(x =>
                    x.id === stage.id ? { ...x, name } : x
                  )
                );
              }}
              value={stage.name || ""}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

This how my data looks:

```
[
  {
    name: "First Stage",

  },
  {
    name: "Second Stage",    
  },
  {
    name: "Third Stage",
  }
];
```

Comment: It's happening because onChange, you're setting state values. When you change state values, it re-renders your component. That's why you're losing focus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of key defined using `uuidv4`. Every render react is not able to identify if the input is new or old in array. So it loses focus. Use `id` as key instead of `uuidv4` and it will work just fine.

```
 {stagesState.map(stage => {
        return (
          <div key={stage.id}>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={e => {
                const name = e.target.value;
                setStagesState(currentStage =>
                  currentStage.map(x =>
                    x.id === stage.id ? { ...x, name } : x
                  )
                );
              }}
              value={stage.name || ""}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
```